# What is the real purpose of csrf tokens?

Tags: csrf

When we are dealing with form pages, the recommendation is to use tokens to prevent csrf attacks. I see many csrf tokens set as a hidden HTML field or in the user cookies/headers. I thought that csrf could prevent automate attacks, but actually, these tokens do not stop a hacker from parser the HTML/Cookies, extract the crsf token and then make a request.

So, what is the purpose to have this type of protection?

Comment: No, the purpose is not to stop automation. https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/csrf

Answer (score 0):

Cross-site request forgery (also known as CSRF) is a web security vulnerability that allows an attacker to induce users to perform actions that they do not intend to perform. It allows an attacker to partly circumvent the same origin policy, which is designed to prevent different websites from interfering with each other.
[image: CSRF]
[image Source](https://portswigger.net/web-security/csrf)

From Wikipedia:

> In a CSRF attack, the attacker's goal is to cause an innocent victim to unknowingly submit a maliciously crafted web request to a website that the victim has privileged access to. This web request can be crafted to include URL parameters, cookies and other data that appear normal to the web server processing the request

The site generates a unique token when it makes the form page. This token is required to post/get data back to the server.
The token is generated by site provided only when the page with the form is generated, some other  can't mimic your forms
 they won't have the token and therefore can't post to your site.

Comment: AminM, what's to stop malicioussite.com from doing `$.get('https://vulnerable-website.com/email/changeform')`, parsing the response for the token, and then doing `$.post('https://vulnerable-website.com/email/change?email=pwned@evil-user.net&antiforgerytoken=THEPARSEDTOKEN')`?

Answer (score 0):

A CSRF Token, is sent from the server and is not intended to be persisted anywhere in the browser. It should be implemented as a one time use token (and expire with with the session if it is not used).

Cross Site Request Forgery, is an attack that exploits the target server's trust of the browser. Usually the goal of the attack is privilege escalation: the victim has some privilege, that the attacker does not have. So, the attacker is going to get the victim to make the request on their behalf.

The usual prerequisite, is that the client has been authenticated by the target server, and this authentication is still valid (think about when you open stack exchange in a new window without having logged out, and you aren't required to type in your credentials).

Now that the client is logged into the target server, the attacker will attempt to get the victim to either click on a malicious link (`targetserver.com/user/?do=somethingevil`) or submit a malicious form from either a site the attacker owns or somewhere they can post a link.

> What is the real purpose of csrf tokens?

Remember the token is this ephemeral, random sequence of characters, that the server controls. When the target server is using it, the attacker needs to add the token to the malicious link (`targetserver.com/user/?do=somethingevil&csrf=asdf1234jkl`) or form submission. Getting that link from the server and providing it to the client would require a different vector, hence the use of CSRF tokens helps mitigate CSRF attacks.

CSRF tokens need to be used in conjunction with other measures, [OWASP](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html) has a wholistic approach outlined.